# How do I connect Laravel 7 to Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-7

I'm really surprised the Laravel documentation is limited for explaining how to connect to MS SQL Server. There are two areas that I think need configuration -- the .env file and the database.php. Most examples on the web don't show the same format compared to Laravel 7. I would like to know where I can find the correct info for the following.

- How to tell what port my DB is on
- What to enter for URL
- What to enter for HOST
- When testing the connection it says 'driver not found' - is it saying the details are incorrect or is it looking for a missing file?
- before changing the database.php file it has the word **forge** as the second argument for the **env()** function - what is forge???

If anyone can point me to a good resource id be in your debt!

````
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test_db_1
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```
````

and the database.php...

```
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'), ...
...
 'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test_db_1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

Comment: I think port 3306 is for MySQL. On the machine running SQL Server check in SQL Server Configuration Manager in the Server Protocols configuration to see which port(s) TCP/IP is set to listen on. A default instance is normally 1433.

Answer (score 1):

First, install additional software for the sql server connection. For OSX (Mac M1)

```
    docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
docker run --platform linux/amd64 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<strong-password>" \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 \
   -d \
   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

    brew install perl
    pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
    CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/include' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.11/lib' pecl install pdo_sqlsrv sqlsrv
```

Then edit the .env and uncomment the line in `config/database.php`.

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=xxx
DB_USERNAME=SA
DB_PASSWORD=xxx
```

uncomment this line if you encounter the error about the server cert

```php
'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'true'),
```

Try to use tinker to query any eloquent to verify the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DB_HOST` will always be localhost, so if the database is on the same machine, `127.0.0.1` will be fine. TCP port 1433 is typically the port used by a default instance of SQL Server, set it to `DB_PORT=1433`.

Laravel Forge is a tool for deploying and configuring web applications and can be used to automate the deployment of any web application that uses a PHP server. Since we are using the .env to overwrite the values in config/database.php there is no need to worry about the "forge" values. Finally, you may need to install [drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) on the machine to support PHP and SQL Server.

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=test_db_1
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

**config/database.php**

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `protected $connection = 'sqlsrv'` on your models if you won't change `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`

You can also use `$query = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(...);`

Don't worry for relationships across multiple databases, it depends on your complexity.

For more explanation [read more here (mrvivaldio)](https://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections).