# Is there any way of adding connection parameters to all queries executed by eloquent and Laravel?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I am using SQL server as database to connect from our Laravel project, and need the following connection properties to be set before **all** eloquent queries and raw Laravel queries:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](https://dev.to/mr_steelze/setting-up-a-laravel-project-with-sql-server-and-xampp-wamp-on-windows-3n7k) for the tutorial. Basically what the link did is just changing the default database connection to SQL Server's connection, then from your `.env` file, you can just specify each of your variable by creating new driver at `database.php` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955122/how-do-i-connect-laravel-7-to-microsoft-sql-server) and getting the value from the `.env` file which is the default way of doing so (or you can just directly define the value at `database.php` file). After that, you need to add PHP extensions to connect PHP to SQL Server, then that's it.